# Space in legend between symbol and text in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Dear Experts of gnuplot,

I want to change the spacing between key text and key symbol. [image]

Please help me with this. What command should I use for the purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The space between symbol and key entry is so large because it is reserved for line plots:

```
plot sin(x) with points, cos(x) with lines
```

[image]

If you mix these two styles in one figure, you will want to keep the horizontal spacing. However, if you are sure that you will use only points, then the horizontal space might indeed seem too large. The `samplen` option of `set key` can be used for that purpose, it can even be set to negative: `set key samplen -1` (default is 4)
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail help. It has solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @whoami You're welcome! Could you please accept it as answer?

Comment: Yes, sure I accept it as answer to my question. Thanks.